# Internal org mode links not exporting when buffer is narrowed

Tags: emacs, markdown, org-mode

I need to periodically export to markdown various parts of a narrowed org buffer. When I run `org-md-export-as-markdown` (with `org-export-with-broken-links` set to `t`), the export works fine, except that all the links pointing to parts of the buffer outside the narrowed range fail to export.

For example, consider a buffer that contains the following text:

```
* Heading 1
** Heading 2
See [[*Heading 1][heading 1]].
```

The result of invoking `org-md-export-as-markdown` when the buffer is narrowed to `Heading 2` is the following:

```
## Heading 2
See .
```

I tried using unique IDs instead, but the behavior is the same. Is there an org variable that controls how these links are exported, or a workaround to force Emacs to include these links? I understand that, since they point to a reference that doesn't exist in the exported file, the links would not work. However, I can easily automate the process of fixing these broken links, whereas if the links do not export at all, my only option is to recreate them manually.

My Org version is 9.4.4.

Comment: Version? When I try with Org mode 9.4.4, I get an error `user-error: Unable to resolve link: "*Heading 1" ` and no output file is produced. There is `org-export-with-broken-links`  which when set to `t` produces output like the one you get. Maybe you have it set to `t`?

Comment: Why not widen the buffer before exporting? Assuming your cursor is somewhere inside `Heading 2`, you can `C-x n w` to widen, `C-c C-e m m` to export, `C-x n s` to narrow to the subtree again.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I set ```org-export-with-broken-links``` to ```t```. I can widen the buffer, but because the file it is visiting is very large (~3Mb), it takes about 30 seconds to export. I need to do this a dozen or so times per day, so I'd like to export without narrowing if possible.

My org version is also 9.4.4.

Comment: How about doing `(setq org-export-with-broken-links 'mark)`? Or `#+OPTIONS: broken-links:mark` at the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I had assumed that the only values for ```org-export-with-broken-links``` were nil and non-nil—should have read the documentation.